# Python 3 - Type "exit" to exit program anytime in guessing game

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing the practicepython challenges. Where I try to make a simple number guessing game where you can type exit at anytime instead of a guess to exit the game.

Here's where my code's at, at the moment.

```
import random
def run():
number = random.randint(1,9)
print ("Hi, your mission is to guess the secret number. You\'ll get a clue, it\'s a number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). \n Type exit whenever to exit game.")
guess = ""
guesses = 0
while guess != number:
    guess = (input("Guess a number: "))
    guesses += 1
    if int(guess) < number:
        print ("Too low...")
    elif int(guess) > number: print("Too high!")
    elif str(guess) == ("exit"):
        return "Thank you for playing!"
    else:
        print ("Good job! You guessed the secret word in {} number of tries!".format(guesses))
        run()
run()
```

Ok! So the part that does not work is "elif str(guess) == ("exit"):
        return "Thank you for playing!""

Edited:

```
import random
def run():
while True:
    number = random.randint(1,9)
    print ("Hi, your mission is to guess the secret number. You\'ll get a clue, it\'s a number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). \n Type exit whenever to exit game.")
    guess = ""
    guesses = 0
    while guess != number:
        guess = (input("Guess a number: "))
        guesses += 1
        if type(guess) is int and guess < number:
            print ("Too low...")
        elif type(guess) is int and guess > number: print("Too high!")
        elif type(guess) is str and guess == ("exit"):
            return "Thank you for playing!"
        else:
            print ("Good job! You guessed the secret word in {} number of tries!".format(guesses))
            break
```

run()

But this only gives me the else statement? ("Good job! You....)"

Solved by rewriting and took some help by the solution and realised the whole order was messed up. New working code:

```
print("Hi, your mission is to guess the secret number. You\'ll get a clue, it\'s a number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). \nType exit whenever to exit game.")
import random
number = random.randint(1, 9)
guess = 0
count = 0
    while guess != number and guess != "exit":
    guess = input("\nWhat's your guess? ")
    if guess == "exit":
        print ("Thank you for playing!")
        break
    guess = int(guess)
    count += 1
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low!")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high!")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        print("And it only took you", count, "tries!")
```

Comment: try elif str(guess) == "exit"

Answer (score 0):

You're performing `int()` and `str()` typecasting on the value of `guess`, then doing comparisons without first checking the actual data type. This is never a good thing, as once you input "exit" (or any other `str`, `float`, or other invalid type for that matter), the program will throw a `ValueError`.

Instead of doing typecasting, you can instead check the type of `guess` as per below. This makes typecasting unnecessary, as we already know the type of `guess` is what the program expects.

```
if type(guess) is int and guess < number:
    print ("Too low...")
elif type(guess) is int and guess > number: 
    print("Too high!")
elif type(guess) is str and guess == ("exit"):
    return "Thank you for playing!"
```

Comment: Ok! So that solved the exit problem alright!
But now it just prints the else statement... Don't know if I changed it correctly...

Comment: Also some general comments on your code: As you define a reasonably reachable exit condition for your `while` loop, you can change this to `while True:` and remove the method call to `run()` when the number is guessed correctly. You are also not re-rolling the value of `number` once you're in the `run()` method!

Comment: There are some other issues I see with your code (Hint: you should try explicitly checking if number == guess instead of your else statement), but seems your question specifically asked about getting "exit" working, this is what I focused on.

Comment: Thank you for helping! Please take a look at my edited code above... It only prints the else statement... Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a recursive call when the user correctly guesses a number, so even if the user enters "exit" in the next game, it would only return to the calling `run`, rather than the main program. You should use an outer`while` loop to keep the game going after the user correctly guesses a number instead:

```
import random
def run():
    while True:
        number = random.randint(1,9)
        print ("Hi, your mission is to guess the secret number. You\'ll get a clue, it\'s a number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). \n Type exit whenever to exit game.")
        guess = ""
        guesses = 0
        while int(guess) != number:
            guess = (input("Guess a number: "))
            guesses += 1
            if guess == "exit":
                return "Thank you for playing!"
            elif int(guess) < number:
                print ("Too low...")
            elif int(guess) > number:
                print("Too high!")
            else:
                print ("Good job! You guessed the secret word in {} number of tries!".format(guesses))
run()
```

Comment: Your code immediately throws a `ValueError` once it reaches the `while` loop, because it's tying to compare an `int` with a `str`.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed it then.